# Finding value of constant c from joint pdf

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

$f(x,y) = c(x^2 + y^2)$, for $x = -1, 0, 1, 3$ and $y = -1, 2, 3$.

I missed a couple classes so I've only seen joint pdf represented in a table ... not an equation. If someone could just walk me through the steps in solving this simply I'd really appreciate it.
Do I solve for $c$ by inserting values for $x$ and $y$ into the equation?

Thanks!

Comment: Part of the definition of a pdf is about the *sum* of the values of the function. Do you know what that part is?

Comment: You can draw a table if that will help. For example the entry corresponding to $x=-1$, $y=-1$ is $c((-1)^2+(-1)^2)$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint:

Fill out this table
\begin{array}{r|c|c|c}
f(x,y)&-1&2&3\\\hline
-1&2c&\phantom{2c}&\phantom{2c}\\\hline
0&&&\\\hline
1&&&\\\hline
3&&&
\end{array}
and use the fact that marginal densities sum to $1$. I filled in the first one.

Comment: Makes so much sense. Thanks!

Comment: @user289505 No problem. Help respondents gain reputation by clicking the [check mark](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).